# Pandas - dataframe to BigQuery

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I have a df like the attached one:

[image]

I'd like to iter over this df and write data into bq, the table's schema is something like: |coicop|unit|geo\time|period|value|
Where "period" and "value", in this case, would be "2021M05" and "108.36" or "2021M06" and "107.36".
I'm struggling to rotate these fields in order to be merged into the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.melt`:

```
In [965]: df = df.melt(id_vars=['coicop', 'unit', 'geo\time'], var_name='period')

In [966]: df
Out[966]: 
  coicop unit geo\time   period   value
0   CP03  I15       AT  2021M05  108.36
1   CP03  I15       BE  2021M05  106.66
2   CP03  I15       BG  2021M05   97.33
3   CP03  I15       CH  2021M05  112.49
4   CP03  I15       CY  2021M05  101.30
5   CP03  I15       AT  2021M06  107.36
6   CP03  I15       BE  2021M06  106.65
7   CP03  I15       BG  2021M06   97.06
8   CP03  I15       CH  2021M06  110.42
9   CP03  I15       CY  2021M06  103.56
```

Then write this `df` into BQ.